# iOS cannot find pod specification for AWS pods

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, cocoapods

I've looked around for an answer to this but could not find anything useful. According to AWS you just add the following to your pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'AWSCore'
pod 'AWSAutoScaling'
pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
pod 'AWSEC2'
pod 'AWSElasticLoadBalancing'
pod 'AWSKinesis'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSSES'
pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
pod 'AWSSNS'
pod 'AWSSQS'
pod 'AWSCognito'
```

When I do this I get "[!] Unable to find a specification for `AWSCore`"

My full pod file is the following. Note that if I exclude the AWS pods and just have AFNetworking, there is no problem, so I believe cocoapods is installed correctly.

```
target :myApp do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'AWSCore'
pod 'AWSAutoScaling'
pod 'AWSCloudWatch'
pod 'AWSDynamoDB'
pod 'AWSEC2'
pod 'AWSElasticLoadBalancing'
pod 'AWSKinesis'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'AWSSES'
pod 'AWSSimpleDB'
pod 'AWSSNS'
pod 'AWSSQS'
pod 'AWSCognito'

pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When installing CocoaPods, did you run `pod setup` as well?

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
$ pod setup
```

If you have already done this, you can set it up again with a clean state:

```
$ pod repo remove master
$ pod setup
```

Comment: Removing the master and running setup again worked. Greatly appreciated!